# What’s the best way to handle threading with multiple NSStreams?

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsstream

Sorry, but I have to give a little intro first.

I have a class called `MJPEGStreamer`. It uses `NSOutputStream` and `NSInputStream` to stream MJPEG data. I will have up to 16 of these classes running simultaneously.

At first, I was just doing this in my main class:

```
MJPEGStreamer *client = ...;
[client start];
```

And in `MJPEGStreamer.m`:

```
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

But this was giving me very poor performance and all sorts of errors. I assumed that I was running all of these `NSStream`s on the main thread, so I changed this call:

```
[client start]
```

to this:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(start) toTarget:client withObject:nil];
```

After a little debugging, I found that it was *creating* these threads, but not stopping them properly. It would close the `NSStream`s, but the thread was still there.

I then started wondering what would be the best way to do this:

- Should I keep it the way it is, just making sure to kill the threads when I close the `NSStream`s? (How do I kill the thread?)
- Should I make one new thread that all of the `MJPEGStreamer` classes will run on?
- Should I use `NSOperationQueue`?